# I have a problem which is sorting by two fields with comparator in java

Tags: java, comparator

So I'm trying to sort this arrayList by state and then city (if there are duplicate states then compare city). But I can't get it to work as it only sorts the state or the city. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 class StateCityComparator implements Comparator<Customer>{

  /**
   * Comapre method that compares Customers by state and city
   * @param first, second which are the numbers of the customer which needs to be compared
   */
 public int compare(Customer first, Customer second){      

  // Getting the state
  String fir = first.getState();
  String sec = second.getState();
  int state = fir.compareTo(sec);
  int city =  first.getCity().compareTo(second.getCity());             

  // Comparing the state
  if (state < 0)
     return -1;
  if ( state == 0  ){      /* The problem is here */
     return city;
  }
  return state;

}// End of compareStateCity

} // end StateCityComparator
```

This is part of the output:

```
Sorted by State and City:

3 Mapleview Drive              Huntsville             AL 358030000
2421 West Industrial Way       Berkeley               CA 947100000
2421 West Industrial Way       Berkeley               CA 947100000
4223 Halster Way               Berkeley               CA 947101234
4223 Halster Way               Berkeley               CA 947104321
4 Rocky Way                    Colorado Springs       CO 809410000
4 Rocky Way                    Colorado Springs       CO 809410000
5665 MassPike Circle           Sandy Hook             CT 064820000
45A Sturgeon Dr., Bldg. 5      Ft. Pierce             FL 349510000
45A Sturgeon Dr., Bldg. 5      Ft. Pierce             FL 349510000
6665 Peachtree Lane            Atlanta                GA 303280000
1 Washington Complex           Boston                 MA 021010000
45521 Pilgrim Circle           Nantucket              MA 025540000
```

Comment: *it only sorts the state or the city* meaning? Can you post sample data and the result after sorting?

Comment: It sorts only state by alphabetical order and then it doesn't sort the city or the other way around.

Comment: In the output everything is sorted correctly, even for the case of Boston, Nantucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want (keeping the top part of your code the same):

```
class StateCityComparator implements Comparator<Customer> {

    /**
     * Compare method that compares Customers by state and city
     * @param first, second which are the numbers of the customer which needs to be compared
     */
    @Override
    public int compare(Customer first, Customer second){

        // Getting the state
        String fir = first.getState();
        String sec = second.getState();
        int state = fir.compareTo(sec);
        int city =  first.getCity().compareTo(second.getCity());

        // Compare the state, and the city if the states are equal
        return (state == 0)? city : state;

    }// End of compareStateCity

} //
```

Or more concisely, avoiding comparing the cities if you don't have to:

```
class StateCityComparator implements Comparator<Customer> {

    /**
     * Compare method that compares Customers by state and city
     * @param first, second which are the numbers of the customer which needs to be compared
     */
    @Override
    public int compare(Customer first, Customer second){
        int state = first.getState().compareTo(second.getState());
        return (state != 0)? state : first.getCity().compareTo(second.getCity());

    }// End of compareStateCity

} //
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. In fact I already had the correct answer I just thought that I didn't. It sorted the states in correct alphabetical order and then whenever there is a duplicate it sorted only the duplicates with the same state. Which means that I can't have both columns sorted alphabetically. That was confusing me.

Answer (score 3):

You can pretty easily compose a `Comparator` for data objects, using [`Comparator.comparing(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) and [`Comparator.thenComparing(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.function.Function-) like so:

```
public static final Comparator<Customer> STATE_CITY_COMPARATOR =
    Comparator.comparing(Customer::getState).thenComparing(Customer::getCity);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Manually implementing the `Comparator` interface is error-prone.

Comment: I like this answer personally.  I gave it a +1.  I disagree, however, that this is "the right answer".  The right answer caters to the OPs gaining of understanding of how to attack problems as much as it does how to solve a problem in the absolutely most concise and least-error-prone fashion.  The OP might not be able to understand this answer.  If the OP is better served by a more brute force answer that mirrors what he/she was trying to do and learn, then that could be the "best answer".  It's up to the OP to decide what's best for his/her needs.